# Problems with float overflow in backpropagation

Tags: python, machine-learning, backpropagation, mnist

In few trained lines, some numbers have too many digits that overflow float precision.

Im new to Machine Learning, Python (my college teacher recommended using Python) and this is my first StackOverflow question.

I googled first, ofc, but i didnt find something to help me.

This http://jrusev.github.io/post/hacking-mnist/ looks like interesting, but i cannot compare to my code because of my lack of experience. (I've always worked as Front-End)

````
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Global variables
outputDictionary = {'0':[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], '1':[0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                '2':[0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], '3':[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0], '4':[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0], 
                '5':[0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0], '6':[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0], '7':[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0], 
                '8':[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0], '9':[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1] }

learningRate = 0.2
middleLayerSize = 100
outputSize = 10
inputSize = 11

v = np.random.uniform(-1.00, 1.00,(inputSize, middleLayerSize)) # [linhas, middleLayerSize]
w = np.random.uniform(-1.00, 1.00,(middleLayerSize, outputSize)) # [middleLayerSize, outputSize]
errors = []

inputCsv = pd.read_csv('a.csv')
inputData = []

# Functions
def prepareData():
    for row in inputCsv.itertuples(index=False):
        arrRow = list(row)

        for i in range(len(arrRow)):
            if(i != 0):
                arrRow[i] = float(arrRow[i]) / 255

        inputData.append(arrRow)

def train(maxEpochs):
    global errors
    global graph
    global inputData

    for epoch in range(maxEpochs):
        errorCount = 0
        print('Period ' + str(epoch))

        for row in inputData:
            expectedNumber = row.pop(0)
            expectedNumberObj = outputDictionary[str(expectedNumber)]
            zIn = calcZIn(row)
            zOutput = calcDelta(zIn, middleLayerSize)
            yIn = calcYIn(zOutput)

            yOutput = calcDelta(yIn, outputSize)

            validate = validadeOutput(expectedNumberObj, yOutput)

            if(validate == False):
                errorCount+= 1;

                propagateError(expectedNumberObj, row, yOutput, zOutput, zIn, yIn)

        errors.append(errorCount)
        print(errorCount)

def calcZIn(row): 
    result = []

    for j in range(middleLayerSize):
        result.append(0)
        for i in range(inputSize):
            result[j] += v[i,j] * row[i]

    return result

def calcYIn(zOutput): 
    result = []

    for j in range(outputSize):
        result.append(0)
        for i in range(middleLayerSize):
            result[j] += w[i,j] * zOutput[i]

    return result


def calcDelta(arr, arrSize):
    deltas = []

    for i in range(arrSize):
        deltas.append(activationFunction(arr[i]))

    return deltas

def activationFunction(x):
    return 1.0 / (1.0 + np.exp(-x))

def validadeOutput(targetObj, yOutput):
    for i in range(len(yOutput)):
        if(targetObj[i] != yOutput[i]):
            return False

    return True

def propagateError(expectedArr, row, yOutput, zOutput, zIn, yIn):
    errorY = calcError(expectedArr, yOutput, yIn, outputSize)
    errorW = calcWeightCorrection(errorY, zOutput, middleLayerSize, outputSize)

    sumError = sumDelta(errorY, w, middleLayerSize, outputSize)
    errorZ = calcError(sumError, zOutput, zIn, middleLayerSize)
    errorV = calcWeightCorrection(errorZ, row, inputSize, middleLayerSize)

    updateWeight(w, errorW, middleLayerSize, outputSize)
    updateWeight(v, errorV, inputSize, middleLayerSize)


def calcError(expectedArr, outputArr, inArr, size):
    error = []

    for i in range(size):
        error.append((expectedArr[i] - outputArr[i]) * inArr[i] * (1.0 - inArr[i]));

    return error

def calcWeightCorrection(error, output, lenght1, length2):
    delta = [];
    for i in range(lenght1):
        delta.append([])
        for j in range(length2):
            delta[i].append(learningRate * error[j] * output[i])

    return delta

def sumDelta(error, weights, lenght1, length2):
    delta = []

    for i in range(lenght1):
        deltaValue = 0.0
        for j in range(length2):
            deltaValue += error[j] * weights[i][j];

        delta.append(deltaValue)

    return delta

def updateWeight(weight, delta, lenght1, length2):
    # (lenght1)
    # print(length2)
    for i in range(lenght1):
        for j in range(length2):
            # print(str(i) + ' - ' + str(j))
            weight[i][j] += delta[i][j]


# Execution

prepareData()
train(1)```
````

Comment: If there's a stack trace associated w/ the overflow then you should post it. It may help to describe the inputs as well.